# Functions and GLMs in R

Tags: r, function, glm, tweedie

I'm a relatively new R user, and I'm trying to create a function to be used in a bootstrap of standard errors in a GLM in R.  If I run the GLM by itself like this...

```
glm(glm.formula,
    family = tweedie(var.power=1.5,link.power=0),
    data=coll.train,
    subset=1:records,
    weights=EXPOSURE_COLL)
```

...it runs just fine.  Currently the "1:records" is just selecting the entire data set.  In the future I would like to replace it with a random sampling of the records.

However, if I take this same code and put it inside a function...

```
boot.fn=function(data,index){
      return(coef(glm(glm.formula,
                      family = tweedie(var.power=1.5,link.power=0),
                      data=data,
                      subset=index,
                      weights=EXPOSURE_COLL
                      )))  
}
```

...and call the function as follows...

```
boot.fn(coll.train,1:records)
```

...I get the following error message:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'index' not found
```

This seems fairly straightforward, so I'm a little puzzled as to what the issue is.  The most frustrating thing about this is that I took the bones of this code from a textbook, so it should work. I'm not sure what I did to mess it up.

Any help anyone can provide is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This will be a scoping problem. You dont show it but you will be passing the formula somehow, which will cause an issue.. So wrap with `return(eval(substitute(coef(... plus the rest of your code`

Comment: That was it - thanks!